# How to add rows of controls with a button click on a WPF app using c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very simple requirement. I've a WPF app, which currently has 2 grids. The 1st grid is supposed to hold a data entry form of sorts and the 2nd grid just has a button "Add".

```
<Window x:Class="Desing.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Desing" Height="600" Width="850"
>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid x:Name="entryGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Content="SL NO"/>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Content="DESCRIPTION"/>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Content="UNIT"/>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3" Content="UOM"/>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4" Content="RATE"/>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="5" Content="AMOUNT"/>
                
                <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
                <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"/>
                <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5"/>
            </Grid>
            
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <Button Width="50" Content="Add" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I want is when I click the Add button a new row of the textbox's with same property should be added to the view .i.e. upon button click it will add to the xaml another `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>` and

```
        <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4"/>
        <TextBox Margin="5 2 8 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5"/>
```

And the view will become

[image]

from
[image]

and so on...

I've tried the below code:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RowDefinition newRow = new RowDefinition();
    newRow.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    entryGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow);
    
    int rowCount = entryGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
    
    TextBox[] textBoxes = new TextBox[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
    {
        textBoxes[i] = new TextBox();
        textBoxes[i].Margin = new Thickness(5, 2, 8, 2);
        textBoxes[i].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        textBoxes[i].Height = 25;
        Grid.SetRow(textBoxes[i], rowCount + 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(textBoxes[i], i);
        entryGrid.Children.Add(textBoxes[i]);
    }
    
    MessageBox.Show("New row added!");
}
```

But it only works the 1st time I click the button, on subsequent clicks the new rows do not add.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem here? If you go with button click just implement the adding logic in the handler.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik What is the best way to implement the adding logic ?

Comment: By adding the button click it looks like you've opted out to go non-MVVM way - this is easy (just add the row definition to the grid + controls). In MVVM style it would probably require some thinking (also as did not do anything in WPF for more than a year ago)

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I've updated the question by adding the current coding I have for this on button click but it works only the 1st time I click. If I click the button more than once then no new row adds, can you help me with that?

Comment: `rowCount + 1` is not correct. You've already added that `RowDefinition`. Additionally when `RowCount`  is 1 you should set `Row` to be 0. Use `rowCount-1` and it should work.

Comment: You should check out the `DataGrid` control. It's a complete data table and allows you to dynamically create the data rows and saves you *a lot* of work. What you are doing is not a good programming style at all. Your solution is not dynamic as every data line has to be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `TextBox[]`.

Also, since the index of `RowDefinitions` is zero-based, you should set set the `Grid.Row` attached property to `entryGrid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1`.

Try this:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RowDefinition newRow = new RowDefinition();
    newRow.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    entryGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow);

    int rowCount = entryGrid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Margin = new Thickness(5, 2, 8, 2);
        textBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        textBox.Height = 25;
        Grid.SetRow(textBox, rowCount);
        Grid.SetColumn(textBox, i);
        entryGrid.Children.Add(textBox);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("New row added!");
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, you might want to check out how to use the `DataGrid` control or an `ItemsControl` to repeat items but the above sample code should fix your current attempt.